# Rails render hash in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to render key value pairs from a hash.

Here is the hash

```
 @the_object_pairs = { :building_permits => '#',  :new_owners => '#'}
```

I have tried the following views

I've tried without raw

```
<%= raw @the_object_pairs.map do |key, value|  %>
```

with

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
```

and I get #

when I try without raw and following inside the block

```
"<h1>"Hi</>".html_safe
```

I get

```
".html_safe "
".html_safe [" \"<div></div>\".html_safe\n", " \"<div></div>\".html_safe\n"]
```

I've tried several other combinations using the key value pairs with no luck at all. I've also tried each and each_pair instead of map.

Does anyone know how to properly render html when hashes are involved.

Comment: Your code is not clearly showing what exactly you are trying. Please update it.

Answer (score 2):

From what you wrote in your question, it is difficult to tell what data from the hash you want displayed in your view and where in your view you want it, but here are a few suggestions:

If you want to display a single item from your hash, just put something like this in your view:

```
<%= @the_object_pairs[:building_permits] %>
```

Or if you want to show all of the items in the hash in a vertical list, you can do:

```
<% @the_object_pairs.each do |key,value| %>
   The key is: <%= key %> 
   The value is: <%= value %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: I want to render the contents of the hash:                   @the_object_pairs = { :building_permits => '#',  :new_owners => '#'}                    
in the views. For the time being just being able to render the keys and their corresponding values in table for example.

Comment: I edited the answer above to make it a little more obvious by using the variable names and hash keys from your example.  Does this not work for you?  If not, give me an example of what values are stored in the hash key :building_permits.  Is it just 1 value or a nested array or hash of values?

Comment: Also, I'm still a bit confused by your question.  Does your hash contain HTML code?  Because otherwise, there is no need to use raw or html_safe to display the keys and values.  And also, you can use .each instead of .map, as I used in my answer above.